# Query bamboo API for logs on builds through postman

Tags: postman, bamboo

I have what I believed is a rather simple task however, it is really starting to frustrate me. So here is the scenario. I have a Bamboo in-house server and I am trying to use Postman to query the logs for latest build information for all projects. I am getting information such as the projects and keys. However, when I try taking the name and key and putting it into the parameters, I either get errors or the information is the same.

Comment: As an aside, I am also willing to use PowerShell to accomplish this task, I just need it to loop through and grab the projectKey which is unique to show logging information.